# Why am I unable to target a mapped out <li> from the button mapped out with it with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process of learning react and am working on a pretty simple food ordering app that maps through a list of meals in a component named AvailableMeals and would allow a user to hit the add to cart button on each mapped out item to add it to cart.

Right now though, I am unable to get my add button to target the LI that it is connected to. I have tried putting the targeting function in multiple places and tried to target different things (this, this.name, e.target.value, etc) but everything still comes up with undefined or throws an unable to read undefined error. I have even tried to use useContext, but still nothing. I will add the components that are relevant to this below.

My component tree is MealForm -> MealItem -> MealItemForm -> Input and will paste the markup here in that order.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
const MealForm =(props) => {


    return (
        <ul className='mealForm'>
            
                <MealItem  meals={AvailableMeals} />
            
        </ul>
    )


}
```

```
const MealItem =(props) => {

    // const mealsCtx = useContext(AvailableMeals);
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(null)
    const [curMeal, setCurMeal] = useState(null)

    const addToCartHandler = (e, props) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this); //This is what I am using to try and target
    }

    if ( props.meals.length === 0) {
        return( <h2>No meals found!!</h2>)
    } else{
        return (
            <Card >
                    {AvailableMeals.map((meal)=> {
                        return<>
                            <ul className='mealItem'>
                                <div className='mealItem-info'>
                                    <li>{meal.name}</li>
                                    <li>{meal.description}</li>
                                    <li>{meal.price}</li>
                                    <MealItemForm 
                                    id={meal.id}
                                    key={meal.id}
                                    name={meal.name}
                                    description={meal.description}
                                    onSub={addToCartHandler}
                                />
                                </div>


                            </ul>
                        </>
                        
                    })};

            </Card>
        )

    }

};
```

```
const MealItemForm = (props) => {

    return(
        <form onSubmit={props.onSub}>
            <Input label="Amount  " input={{
                id: 'amount_' + props.id,
                type: 'number',
                min: '1',
                max: '10',
                step: '1',
                defaultValue: '1'
            }} 
                
            />
            <button> + Add</button>
        </form>        
        )
}
```

```
const Input = (props) => {

    return (
        <div >
            <label htmlFor={props.input.id}>{props.label}</label>
            <input {...props.input}/>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: On `MealItemForm`, try this: `<form name={props.name} onSubmit={props.onSub}>`. Then, on `MealItem` within `addToCartHandler` add a console like so: `console.log(e.target.name);`. Wondering if that will show the corresponding `meal.name`. Please share your feedback on how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is able to use stack-snippets to provide a working demo of one's code. This answer addresses the OP's question in trying to identify which meal's click event was invoked.

**Changes significant to the question:**

1. On the component: `MealItemForm`, changed below:
   `<form name={props.name} onSubmit={props.onSub}>`
2. On the component: `MealItem`, changed `addToCartHandler` method:
   `console.log('mean-name corresponding to the clicked-item: ', e.target.name);`

**Impact observed:**

The `console.log` properly displays the `meal.name` corresponding to the item's whose button was clicked.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Input = (props) => {
    return (
        <div >
            <label htmlFor={props.input.id}>{props.label}</label>
            <input {...props.input}/>
        </div>
    )
};


const MealItemForm = (props) => {
    return(
        <form name={props.name} onSubmit={props.onSub}>
            <Input label="Amount  " input={{
                id: 'amount_' + props.id,
                type: 'number',
                min: '1',
                max: '10',
                step: '1',
                defaultValue: '1'
            }} 
                
            />
            <button> + Add</button>
        </form>        
        )
};

const MealItem = (props) => {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState(null);
    const [curMeal, setCurMeal] = useState(null);

    const addToCartHandler = (e, props) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('mean-name corresponding to the clicked-item: ', e.target.name); 
    };

    if ( props.meals.length === 0) {
        return (<h2>No meals found!!</h2>)
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
              {
                props.meals.map(meal => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <ul className='mealItem'>
                        <div className='mealItem-info'>
                            <li>{meal.name}</li>
                            <li>{meal.description}</li>
                            <li>{meal.price}</li>
                            <MealItemForm 
                            id={meal.id}
                            key={meal.id}
                            name={meal.name}
                            description={meal.description}
                            onSub={addToCartHandler}
                        />
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                 )
                })
              }
            </div>
        )
    }
};

const AvailableMeals = [
  {name: 'name 0', description: 'description 0', price: 'price 0', id: '0' },
  {name: 'name 1', description: 'description 1', price: 'price 1', id: '1' },
  {name: 'name 2', description: 'description 2', price: 'price 2', id: '2' },
  {name: 'name 3', description: 'description 3', price: 'price 3', id: '3' },
  {name: 'name 4', description: 'description 4', price: 'price 4', id: '4' }
];

const MealForm =(props) => {
    return (
        <ul className='mealForm'>
                <MealItem  meals={AvailableMeals} />
        </ul>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <MealForm />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```css
.mealItem-info {
  display: flex; border: 2px solid grey; width: fit-content;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 5px;
}
.mealItem-info>li { padding: 20px; margin-left: 25px; }
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @jsNoob is there a reason why this works as opposed to adding this to the same form ```price={props.price} description={props.description}``` and then console logging it the same way? Is it just how the semantics work with being name?

Comment: At this line: `<form name={props.name} onSubmit={props.onSub}>` the code is adding value to HTML-element `form`'s attribute `name`. I think one is able to add custom attributes - so, `price`, `description` should work too. I'm still learning, though.

Comment: That is what I thought as well. It comes up as undefined. Strange though, it does work when I target it like ```e.target.getAttribute('price')```.  I assume there must be some sort of semantic/syntax reason for this though. Either way, it is working now, so I appreciate your help.